# How to restrict onEdit to a specific range and modify a corresponding range(increase by one if true)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to have a cell which counts how many times the checkbox has been set to true.
I tried to do it myselfs and wrote two different solutions but neither of them works as I want them to.

The first one:

```
function onEdit(e){
  // count warnings
  var warning1 = sheet1.getRange(6,10,lastRow,1).getValues();
  var warning1count = sheet1.getRange(6,21,lastRow,1).getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){
    if(warning1[i][0] == true){
      sheet1.getRange(6+i,21,1,1).setValue(warning1count[i][0] +1);
   }
}
}
```

This one increases the value by one to the cells that are TRUE whenever something changes in the whole sheet, I don't know how to specify it to make it add one whenever it is set TRUE and ignore all other edits
I can't use a reference to a speciffic cell here, because I have every row looking the same and I want to count how many times true has been set in any of them separately.

The second one:

```
/**
 * Function to count warnings
 * 
 * @param {cell} cell Original value
 * @param {number} number New value
 * @return How many times warning was given
 * @customfunction
 */
function warning(cell, number){
var number = 0
  if(cell == true){
      ++number;
}
return number
}
```

It works just in a specific cell, but it gives back 0 or 1, so it basically tells me if the cell is set to true, I want the value to stay when it's false and increase by one whenever it is set to true.

EDIT: the other post doesn't have an answer for my question. It has only  a reference to a specific cell - which I can't use in my situation.
I have a range of cells (J6:J) which I want to interract with another range of cells (U6:U) but I want to change the value in U6 only if J6 is set true, the same with U7-J7 etc. I can't make it work, because whenever I use range it changes in the whole range whenever I edit any cell, so for example - if I set J6 to true it gives me 1 in U6, but when I set J7 true it adds one to U6 and U7, because both of corresponding cells (J6 and J7) are set true. I don't know how to make U6 react ONLY to J6.

I added a photo to make it easier to explain, I basically want the cell on the right to count how many times the cell on the left has been set to true.

[image]

Comment: So use a reference to a range? If you have trues in A1:A10, use B1:B10  to put the results in. Kindly make a substantial [edit] with [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show  your existing structure and "Expected results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict your onEdit like this:

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const requiredRange = {
      //J6:J
      startRow: 6,
      endRow: Infinity,
      startColumn: 10,
      endColumn: 10,
    },
    requiredSheets = ['Sheet1'],
    editedRange = e.range,
    editedSheetName = editedRange.getSheet().getName(),
    isEditedRangeInRequiredSheet = () =>
      requiredSheets.some((sheetName) => editedSheetName === sheetName),
    [editedRow, editedCol] = [editedRange.rowStart, editedRange.columnStart],
    isEditedRangeInRequiredRange = () =>
      editedRow >= requiredRange.startRow &&
      editedRow <= requiredRange.endRow &&
      editedCol >= requiredRange.startColumn &&
      editedCol <= requiredRange.endColumn,
    columnOffset = 12;
  
  //exit code
  if (
    !isEditedRangeInRequiredSheet() &&
    !isEditedRangeInRequiredRange() &&
    !editedRange.isChecked()
  )
    return;
  
  //else
  const warningCountRange = editedRange.offset(0, columnOffset);
  warningCountRange.setValue(warningCountRange.getValue() + 1);
}
```